# Rails - Secure HTTP login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http

I'm currently writing a small web app that needs admin login. Since there will only be one administrator, I'm reluctant to write a fully functional admin system for it. However, since basic HTTP login uses unencrypted username and password, it's obviously not acceptable at a security level. So is there anyway to securely use HTTP login, or other easy-to-make but secure login method?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have real security of the password on the wire is with the HTTPS protocol.

You can use HTTP Basic auth over this protocol and do something simple like hard coding the user/password in the application.  I've done this a number of times by putting the user/password into ENV vars on the server so they're not added to the source code repository.  I then use Rails' built in http_basic* helpers to allow access to specific controller actions:

e.g.

```
# Controller
class FooController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => Rails.application.config.foo_user,
    :password => Rails.application.config.foo_password

  def index
    ...
  end
end

# Initializer - config/initializers/foo_auth.rb
Fooapp::Application.config.foo_user = ENV["FOO_USER"]
Fooapp::Application.config.foo_password = ENV["FOO_PASSWORD"]
```

I would recommend that as soon as you need more than one user that you use something like Devise, as the password management and storage become a problem pretty quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to authenticate your admin. With devise you can protect ad the controller level (with `before_filter :authenticate_users` in the controller who relate to your admin page). Devise will encrypt and salt your password and store it in your db.

For extra security you can add ssl, so both username and password won't be transmitted in clear text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's a few different options. If you're looking for a full-featured solution, check out devise.

It's pretty straightforward and will meet your requirements:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Per the documentation:

> **Database Authenticatable**: encrypts and stores a password in the database to validate the authenticity of a user while signing in. The authentication can be done both through POST requests or HTTP Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a gem which implements secure authorization and ACLs.

You will need to use HTTPS if you plan to prevent plaintext passwords being transmitted over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is an admin panel solution.
There are two good ones
Rails admin https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin
ActiveAdmin http://activeadmin.info

I use both of them in different projects, Rails admin is faster to deploy - works out of the box (just need to run generator). ActiveAdmin requires some configuration upfront.